# How to prove that $\csc x - 2\cos x \cot 2x = 2 \sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

My idea was...

\begin{align}
& \text{LHS} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {\sin x} - \frac{2\cos x}{\tan2x} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\tan2x-\sin2x}{\sin x\tan2x}
\end{align}

from here, I don't know how to continue, please help! thanks

ps, please teach me how to use the "divide" symbol

Comment: You can write $a/b$ or $a\div b$ or $\dfrac a b$. $\qquad$

Comment: \frac{numerator}{denominator} ,written between the $ symbols

Comment: \dfrac a b will appear the same way regardless of whether it's inline or displayed.  \frac a b, on the other hand, will appear as $\frac a b$ if it's inline and as $\dfrac a b$ if it's displayed. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you'll need a double-angle formula:
$$
\tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x}
$$
or
$$
\tan(2x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)} = \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}.
$$